# Use different ActionSheets Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiactionsheet

I currently try to use 2 action sheets (or maybe more) and want to have different actions for them.

```
 @IBAction func BTActionSheet(sender: AnyObject) {

        let action:UIActionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: "Change Map Type", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Back", destructiveButtonTitle: nil, otherButtonTitles: "Satelite", "Normal","Hybride")
        action.showInView(self.view)
   }
```

This is my ActionSheet to change the MapType

```
func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int){

    println(buttonIndex)
    if buttonIndex == 1{ Map.mapType = MKMapType.Satellite }
    if buttonIndex == 2{ Map.mapType = MKMapType.Standard }
    if buttonIndex == 3{ Map.mapType = MKMapType.Hybrid }
}
```

So want to add a 2. ActionSheet that does something like

```
 @IBAction func BTActionSheet1(sender: AnyObject) {

        let action1:UIActionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: "secound", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Back", destructiveButtonTitle: nil, otherButtonTitles: "one", "two")
        action.showInView(self.view)
   }
```

and use this

```
func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int){

    println(buttonIndex)
    if buttonIndex == 1{ println("otheone") }
    if buttonIndex == 2{ println("otheone2") }
}
```

How can I check from which ActionSheet my buttonIndex comes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use UIActionSheet's (which inherits from UIView) [`tag`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/tag) property:

```
 @IBAction func BTActionSheet(sender: AnyObject) {

        let action:UIActionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: "Change Map Type", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Back", destructiveButtonTitle: nil, otherButtonTitles: "Satelite", "Normal","Hybride")
        action.tag = 1
        action.showInView(self.view)
   }

 @IBAction func BTActionSheet1(sender: AnyObject) {

        let action1:UIActionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: "secound", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Back", destructiveButtonTitle: nil, otherButtonTitles: "one", "two")
        action1.tag = 2
        action1.showInView(self.view)
   }

func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int){
    if actionSheet.tag == 1
    {
        println(buttonIndex)
        if buttonIndex == 1{ Map.mapType = MKMapType.Satellite }
        if buttonIndex == 2{ Map.mapType = MKMapType.Standard }
        if buttonIndex == 3{ Map.mapType = MKMapType.Hybrid }
    }
    if actionSheet.tag == 2
    {
        println(buttonIndex)
        if buttonIndex == 1{ println("otheone") }
        if buttonIndex == 2{ println("otheone2") }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you can store references to the two action sheets and compare `sender` with them in the delegate method.